# You don't have permission to access /data/test.php on this server

Tags: php, apache

I have created an alias in 000-default.conf file. Under  section

```
Alias /data "/home/user/data"
<Directory "/home/user/data">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and make sure everyone has atleast read access to destination folder /home/user/data. But I'm unable to access file test.php inside that folder. I'm getting permission errors. I have given rwx to everyone, and still the problem persist... help needed

Comment: Did you check if you have a .htaccess file in the `data` folder? If you do, is that denying access?

Comment: no there's no .htaccess file

Comment: Do all of `/home`, `/home/user` and `/home/user/data` have executable rights for who it needs?

Comment: Can you access the folder (directory listing) or other files in the folder? 
What kind of permission error you get?

Comment: I gave the folder ugo+rwx just in case and still I can't access file in browser